# IPhone : Sending a class object into a different function

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to **IOS** Development. I am stuck at a place where I want to use the object from a void function in some other function which I am calling from that void function. Can you tell me how to do it?

Here's the code:

```
-(void)buttonPressed: (id) sender withEvent: (UIEvent *) event{

UIButton *mybtn= (UIButton*) sender;
UserDetails *user;    (user is the object of the UserDetails class which I want to use).
user= [searchResult objectAtIndex.:mybtn.tag];

[self sendInviteData];  (I want to use "user" in this function).

}
```

`SearchResult` is the array which has the search results from a search bar. there is a in each cell. When I am click on a button  I want to get that data in the user object and send it to `sendInvite` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do something like that

```
-(returntype)sendInviteDataForUser:(UserDetails *)user{
    // do something
}
```

then you call it with

```
[self sendInviteDataForUser:user];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make your sendInviteData method take a parameter?

```
- (void)sendInviteData:(UserDetails *)user {
...
```

and just pass it in?

```
[self sendInviteData:user];
```

Comment: Thanks :)...I like the approach.

Comment: Rather annoyingly, @Sebastian's answer is better than mine - his method name explains more what you are trying to do. You should accept his answer :(